# How to convert byte array to custom base string?

Tags: java, encode

I know there are ways to convert to Base36 with `toString` or Base64 with `encodeToString`. However, I would like to how to do it. For example, I am using

```
private static final String BASE = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_=!@#$%^&*()[]{}|;:,.<>/?`~ \\'\"+-";
```

I am able to do it with int with the following code.

```
private String convertBase(int num) {
    String text = "";
    int j = (int) Math.ceil(Math.log(num) / Math.log(BASE.length()));
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        text += BASE.charAt(num % BASE.length());
        num /= BASE.length();
    }
    return text;
}
```

However, the numerical value of the `byte[]` is bigger than `long`.

Comment: I would suggest avoiding `Math.ceil`, `Math.log`, or `+=` on a String, but I would suggest handling negative numbers.  BTW Your program will print empty String for `0`,  Instead of trying to convert an entire `byte[]` at once, you can do it progressively. e.g. three bytes turn into 4 characters in base64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer myself. I used `BigInteger` to solve it.

```
public String baseConvert(final BigInteger number, final String charset) {
    BigInteger quotient;
    BigInteger remainder;
    final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    final BigInteger base = BigInteger.valueOf(charset.length());
    do {
        remainder = number.remainder(base);
        quotient = number.divide(base);
        result.append(charset.charAt(remainder.intValue()));
        number = number.divide(base);
    } while (!BigInteger.ZERO.equals(quotient));
    return result.reverse().toString();
}
```